# Why can't I use LaTeX3 commands inside a macro I define?

Tags: xetex, latex3, l3regex

I'm really wanting to make use of LaTeX3's regular expressions package (`l3regex`) but am struggling to use LaTeX3 commands in general. Code that works on its own in the preamble fails when embedded in a macro. For example, why does this fail?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\newcommand* \blahblah[0] {%
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_set:Nn \l_my_one_tl { That~cat. }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
}

\begin{document}
\blahblah
\end{document}
```

By contrast, if you take the contents of the `\blahblah` macro and put them outside of the `\newcommand*`, then everything works fine. There's something about being inside of the macro definition that's causing problems.

What am I missing?

Comment: `\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff` has to be outside the macro body.

Comment: Although not strictly necessary, I think that "best practice" encourages us to define  `\l_my_one_tl` outside of the macro with `\tl_new:N  \l_my_one_tl` too.